# Jquery Get Multiple Anchor texts of selected div

Tags: jquery

I have a list which contains a div holding multiple anchors. When i select the div i want to get all the anchor text to carry over to the new div. Any ideas?

```js
 $('.mwCont li').on('click', function(event){
  var mweek = $(this).find('ul > li:nth-child(1) > a').text;
  var mwdate = $(this).find('ul > li:nth-child(2) > a').text;
  $('#newdiv1').text(mweek);
  $('#newdiv2').text(mwdate);
 });
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class ="mwBar">
  <section>
   <div class="mwbutton" id="showTop">
    <div class="newdiv1" id="newdiv1">MW 13</div>
    <div class="newdiv2" id="newdiv2">20 Nov - 23 Nov</div>
   </div>
  </section>
 </div>

    <div class="mwCont">
  <div class = "b1">
    <ul>
      <li>
     <div class = "mwdiv">
       <a>MW 5</a>
       <a>26 Dec - 28 Jan</a>
      </div>
    </li>
   </ul>
  </div>
 </div>
```

Comment: Where is `#newdiv1` and `#newdiv2` in your example?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems like the problem lies in the selectors used to find the links and that text is not being called correctly (should be text(), so it executes):

```
$('.mwCont li').on('click', function(event){
    var links = $(this).find('a');
    var mweek = links.eq(0).text();// First link text
    var mwdate = links.eq(1).text();// Second link text
    $('#newdiv1').text(mweek);
    $('#newdiv2').text(mwdate);
});
```